# Create Oracle Function to Perform Count Total Across Rows

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I have a table1 with rows like the following:

```
ID1  ID2 Attempts
01   01  3
02   01  2
03   01  0
04   01  4
05   02  1
06   02  2
```

I need to create a function in oracle that is passed a specific ID2, and return a true or false depending upon whether the number of *Attempts* across identical ID2 values is less than (false) or greater than or equal (true) some *Value* corresponding to *Description*: **Table1 Max Val** in table2:

```
ID   Description      Value
01   Blah             23
02   BlahBlah         12
03   Table1 Max Val   20
```

I have tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION greater(Val IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER AS 
MAXVAL1 CLOB;
MAXVAL2 NUMBER;
BEGIN
select Value into MAXVAL1 from Table2 Where Description = 'Table1 Max Val';
select SUM(Attempts) into MAXVAL2 from Table1 where ID2 = Val;
4:    IF MAXVAL2 < CAST(CAST(MAXVAL AS VARCHAR2(200)) AS NUMBER(10))
5:      RETURN 0;
6:    ELSE
7:      RETURN 1;
8:    END IF;
9:  END;
```

however, it will not compile (doesn't like that casting).

Comment: where is the return datatype of your function?

Comment: also add the error you're getting

Comment: I added the return type of the function (see original post)

Comment: your question and expected output is not clear

Comment: If you return BOOLEAN then you will only be able to use the function in other PL/SQL code, but not in plain SQL (Oracle SQL does not have the BOOLEAN data type, unfortunately). If you want to use it in SQL, you may be better off returning number, with 0 for FALSE and 1 for TRUE.

Comment: Thanks mathguy. I changed return to NUMBER. Still not working

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I have updated the post query by initilizing 2 params where I wasn't before. I hope this clears up some. However, now I realize my real-life situation (above obfiscates some because I can't show actual code) has a CLOB for MAXVAL1 and NUMBER for MAXVAL2. How can I compare the two different data types or else convert the CLOB to a number before comparing? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all assistance. I had two problems:

- Creating a function to perform count totals across rows
- A need to convert a BLOB value to a NUMBER

Here is the code that ended up working for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION greater(Val IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER 
AS 

MAXVAL1 CLOB;
MAXVAL2 NUMBER;
NUM NUMBER;

BEGIN

select Value into MAXVAL1 from Table2 Where Description = 'Table1 Max Val';
select SUM(Attempts) into MAXVAL2 from Table1 where ID2 = Val GROUP BY ID2;

NUM := TO_NUMBER(MAXVAL1);

IF MAXVAL2 < MAXVAL1 THEN
  RETURN 0;
ELSE
  RETURN 1;
END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the context switches in the PL/SQL using a function a table join and use of an analytic and case gets you a 1 or 0...

`Case when sum(T1.Attempts) over (partition by T1.ID2) < T2."value" then 0 else 1 end`

```
;
with Table1 (ID1, ID2, Attempts) as (
SELECT 01,   01,  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 02,   01,  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 03,   01,  0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 04,   01,  4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 05,   02,  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 06,   02,  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 07,   03,  20 FROM DUAL  ),
Table2 (ID, Description, "value") as (
SELECT 01,   'Blah',             23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 02,   'BlahBlah',         12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 03,   'Table1 Max Val',   20 FROM DUAL)
SELECT Case when sum(T1.Attempts) over (partition by T1.ID2) < T2."value" then 0 else 1 end as MyResult
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN table2 T2
 on T1.ID2 = T2.ID
WHERE T2.Description = 'Blah'
```

Simply pass in a where clause parameter for ID and limit results to be the myResult column..

But maybe I don't understand the problem.

or to return a single value/record:

```
with Table1 (ID1, ID2, Attempts) as (
SELECT 01,   01,  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 02,   01,  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 03,   01,  0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 04,   01,  4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 05,   02,  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 06,   02,  2 FROM DUAL  UNION ALL
SELECT 07,   03,  20 FROM DUAL  ),
Table2 (ID, Description, "value") as (
SELECT 01,   'Blah',             23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 02,   'BlahBlah',         12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 03,   'Table1 Max Val',   20 FROM DUAL)
SELECT DISTINCT Case when sum(T1.Attempts) over (partition by T1.ID2) < T2."value" then 0 else 1 end as MyResult
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN table2 T2
 on T1.ID2 = T2.ID 
WHERE T2.Description = 'Blah'
```

Comment: thanks xQbert. I think I am leaning toward a different way. but I will update my code for clarification.